# How to handle child window in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Using Selenium Webdriver,

I want switch between parent and child windows, but I'm not able to get the script to focus on child window. It is not working. Anybody having suggestions to find the solution?

Comment: Welsome to SQA.  If you can expand on your question you are more likely to get a useful answer.  Can you include your code so we can see what is going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver : parent login window closes after login and child window opens](http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18027/selenium-webdriver-parent-login-window-closes-after-login-and-child-window-ope)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames) is docs from seleniumhq explaining exactly what you want, if I'm correct.