# While clicking control should go to the new window

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When clicked on a button, a new window opened but I am unable to perform any operation on this window.

**How do I get selenium to use the new window?**

code:

```
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\selenium\\geckodriver.exe");
        FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("base url");
        driver.navigate().to("new tab");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).click();//While clicking on the button new window is opening 
        //code to perform operation on new window
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathExpression)).click();
```

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- To switch control from child & parent window, we can use windowHandlers.
- If there are multiple child windows you want to access, then iterators will be helpful to navigate
- Hope, below snippet will help you:

  ```
  Set <String> handles =wd.getWindowHandles();
  Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();
  //iterate through your windows

  String parent = it.next();
  System.out.println("parent window:"+parent);

  String newwin = it.next();
  System.out.println("new window:"+newwin);

  wd.switchTo().window(newwin);

  System.out.println("Confirm you are on new window"+wd.getTitle());

  Thread.sleep(5000);

  //perform actions on new window here
  //perform actions on new window here
  //perform actions on new window here

  wd.close();
  wd.switchTo().window(parent);
  ```

Comment: You have already answered the similar one Here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18027/selenium-webdriver-parent-login-window-closes-after-login-and-child-window-ope/20349#20349

You may add a reference to your previous answered question.

Answer (score 1):

The idea, You are not able to deal with controls in new opened window, Because it may be a Frame control, and you should switch to that frame window first to handle the objects inside it.

[Please check the answer here in this similar post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/28423/how-to-locate-element-inside-form-table-element-table-form)

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code. This should work

```
Set<String> winHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        for (String wHandle : winHandles) {
            driver.switchTo().window(wHandle);
        }
```